# stack build on macOS

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

I am new to `haskell`.  I have the simplest of simple programs.

```
#!/usr/bin/env stack
-- stack --resolver lts-13.7 script

module Main where

import Lib

main :: IO ()
main = putStrLn "Hello World"
```

It does work for `stack`

```
 $stack ./Main.hs
Hello World
(base) 19:48:11/app $
```

But it suffers a rather gruesome demise on anything more extravagent:

```
$stack build --test --haddock --no-haddock-hyperlink-source;
Stack has not been tested with GHC versions above 8.6, and using 8.8.3, this may fail
Stack has not been tested with Cabal versions above 2.4, but version 3.0.1.0 was found, this may fail
[1 of 2] Compiling Main             ( /Users/steve/.stack/setup-exe-src/setup-mPHDZzAJ.hs, /Users/steve/.stack/setup-exe-src/setup-mPHDZzAJ.o )
[2 of 2] Compiling StackSetupShim   ( /Users/steve/.stack/setup-exe-src/setup-shim-mPHDZzAJ.hs, /Users/steve/.stack/setup-exe-src/setup-shim-mPHDZzAJ.o )
Linking /Users/steve/.stack/setup-exe-cache/x86_64-osx/tmp-Cabal-simple_mPHDZzAJ_3.0.1.0_ghc-8.8.3 ...
ld64.lld: warning: ignoring unknown argument: --gc-sections
ld64.lld: warning: ignoring unknown argument: -u
(maybe 50 of these ..)
ld64.lld: warning: ignoring unknown argument: -u
ld64.lld: warning: ignoring unknown argument: -search_paths_first
ld64.lld: warning: ignoring unknown argument: -dead_strip_dylibs
ld64.lld: warning: -sdk_version is required when emitting min version load command.  Setting sdk version to match provided min version
Cannot open /Users/steve/.stack/setup-exe-src/setup-mPHDZzAJ.o: bad relocation (Invalid pointer diff) in section __TEXT/__text (r1_address=21c, r1_type=5, r1_extern=1, r1_length=2, r1_pcrel=0, r1_symbolnum=37), (r2_address=21c, r2_type=0, r2_extern=1, r2_length=2, r2_pcrel=0, r2_symbolnum=30)
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
`gcc' failed in phase `Linker'. (Exit code: 1)

--  While building simple Setup.hs using:
      /Users/steve/.stack/programs/x86_64-osx/ghc-8.8.3/bin/ghc-8.8.3 -rtsopts -threaded -clear-package-db -global-package-db -hide-all-packages -package base -main-is StackSetupShim.mainOverride -package Cabal-3.0.1.0 /Users/steve/.stack/setup-exe-src/setup-mPHDZzAJ.hs /Users/steve/.stack/setup-exe-src/setup-shim-mPHDZzAJ.hs -o /Users/steve/.stack/setup-exe-cache/x86_64-osx/tmp-Cabal-simple_mPHDZzAJ_3.0.1.0_ghc-8.8.3
    Process exited with code: ExitFailure 1
```

I tried searching for these but did not run into obvious matches/solutions. Tips?

**Update** `haskell` and `stack` were installed as such:

```
brew install haskell-stack
```

**Another update**  I am trying to navigate to install from the `haskell platform`.

The asker is *not* off in left field but instead following the directions provided by the `Haskell platform` https://www.haskell.org/platform/

[image]

There is *no* download link there so we resort to googling for *download ghcup* which leads us to https://www.haskell.org/ghcup/

Then running the command

```
curl --proto '=https' --tlsv1.2 -sSf https://get-ghcup.haskell.org | sh
```

[image]

The result is:

$curl --proto '=https' --tlsv1.2 -sSf https://get-ghcup.haskell.org | sh

This did install `ghcup` correctly

```
 $ghcup
ghcup 0.0.8
GHC up toolchain installer

USAGE:
    ghcup [FLAGS] <SUBCOMMAND>
```

Next in line: `cabal`.   Google search led me to: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/cabal-install

[image]

I downloaded the cabal-install tarball https://hackage.haskell.org/package/cabal-install-3.2.0.0/cabal-install-3.2.0.0.tar.gz

This one was not so cooperative.  The short version of the errors is:

```
ld64.lld: warning: ignoring unknown argument: -u
ld64.lld: warning: ignoring unknown argument: -search_paths_first
ld64.lld: warning: ignoring unknown argument: -dead_strip_dylibs
ld64.lld: warning: -sdk_version is required when emitting min version load command.  Setting sdk version to match provided min version
Cannot open ./Distribution/Compat/Async.o: bad relocation (Invalid pointer diff) in section __TEXT/__text (r1_address=2338, r1_type=5, r1_extern=1, r1_length=3, r1_pcrel=0, r1_symbolnum=243), (r2_address=2338, r2_type=0, r2_extern=1, r2_length=3, r2_pcrel=0, r2_symbolnum=237)
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
`gcc' failed in phase `Linker'. (Exit code: 1)

Error during cabal-install bootstrap:
Compiling the Setup script failed.
```

Full version of errors is:

```
$./bootstrap.sh 
mktemp: illegal option -- p
usage: mktemp [-d] [-q] [-t prefix] [-u] template ...
       mktemp [-d] [-q] [-u] -t prefix 
Using gcc for C compiler. If this is not what you want, set CC.
Using /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ld instead.
Checking installed packages for ghc-8.8.3...
deepseq is already installed and the version is ok.
binary is already installed and the version is ok.
time is already installed and the version is ok.
transformers is already installed and the version is ok.
mtl is already installed and the version is ok.
text is already installed and the version is ok.
parsec is already installed and the version is ok.
network-uri-2.6.1.0 will be downloaded and installed.
network-2.7.0.0 will be downloaded and installed.
HTTP-4000.3.12 will be downloaded and installed.
zlib-0.6.2 will be downloaded and installed.
random-1.1 will be downloaded and installed.
stm is already installed and the version is ok.
hashable-1.2.7.0 will be downloaded and installed.
async-2.2.1 will be downloaded and installed.
base16-bytestring-0.1.1.6 will be downloaded and installed.
base64-bytestring-1.0.0.1 will be downloaded and installed.
cryptohash-sha256-0.11.101.0 will be downloaded and installed.
resolv-0.1.1.1 will be downloaded and installed.
mintty-0.1.2 will be downloaded and installed.
echo-0.1.3 will be downloaded and installed.
edit-distance-0.2.2.1 will be downloaded and installed.
ed25519-0.0.5.0 will be downloaded and installed.
tar-0.5.1.0 will be downloaded and installed.
digest-0.0.1.2 will be downloaded and installed.
lukko-0.1.1 will be downloaded and installed.
hackage-security-0.6.0.0 will be downloaded and installed.
Cabal-3.2.0.0 will be downloaded and installed.

Downloading Cabal-3.2.0.0...
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  753k    0  753k    0     0  2879k      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 2888k
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 27320    0 27320    0     0   188k      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  189k
[  1 of 236] Compiling Distribution.Compat.Async ( Distribution/Compat/Async.hs, Distribution/Compat/Async.o )
[  2 of 236] Compiling Distribution.Compat.Binary ( Distribution/Compat/Binary.hs, Distribution/Compat/Binary.o )
[  3 of 236] Compiling Distribution.Compat.Directory ( Distribution/Compat/Directory.hs, Distribution/Compat/Directory.o )
[  4 of 236] Compiling Distribution.Compat.Exception ( Distribution/Compat/Exception.hs, Distribution/Compat/Exception.o )
[  5 of 236] Compiling Distribution.Compat.FilePath ( Distribution/Compat/FilePath.hs, Distribution/Compat/FilePath.o )
[  7 of 236] Compiling Distribution.Compat.Internal.TempFile ( Distribution/Compat/Internal/TempFile.hs, Distribution/Compat/Internal/TempFile.o )

( 200 other compiling lines ..)

[230 of 236] Compiling Distribution.Simple.Configure ( Distribution/Simple/Configure.hs, Distribution/Simple/Configure.o )
[231 of 236] Compiling Distribution.Simple.SrcDist ( Distribution/Simple/SrcDist.hs, Distribution/Simple/SrcDist.o )
[232 of 236] Compiling Distribution.Simple.Build ( Distribution/Simple/Build.hs, Distribution/Simple/Build.o )
[233 of 236] Compiling Distribution.Simple.Haddock ( Distribution/Simple/Haddock.hs, Distribution/Simple/Haddock.o )
[234 of 236] Compiling Distribution.Simple.Doctest ( Distribution/Simple/Doctest.hs, Distribution/Simple/Doctest.o )
[235 of 236] Compiling Distribution.Simple ( Distribution/Simple.hs, Distribution/Simple.o )
[236 of 236] Compiling Main             ( Setup.hs, Setup.o )
Linking Setup ...
ld64.lld: warning: ignoring unknown argument: --gc-sections
ld64.lld: warning: ignoring unknown argument: -u

(80 other similar lines..)

ld64.lld: warning: ignoring unknown argument: -u
ld64.lld: warning: ignoring unknown argument: -u
ld64.lld: warning: ignoring unknown argument: -u
ld64.lld: warning: ignoring unknown argument: -search_paths_first
ld64.lld: warning: ignoring unknown argument: -dead_strip_dylibs
ld64.lld: warning: -sdk_version is required when emitting min version load command.  Setting sdk version to match provided min version
Cannot open ./Distribution/Compat/Async.o: bad relocation (Invalid pointer diff) in section __TEXT/__text (r1_address=2338, r1_type=5, r1_extern=1, r1_length=3, r1_pcrel=0, r1_symbolnum=243), (r2_address=2338, r2_type=0, r2_extern=1, r2_length=3, r2_pcrel=0, r2_symbolnum=237)
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
`gcc' failed in phase `Linker'. (Exit code: 1)

Error during cabal-install bootstrap:
Compiling the Setup script failed.
```

**And Another update**

Per a comment from @bradm I have tried the `Haskell Stack` http://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/README/#how-to-install .  The same errors occur as at beginning of my question. I did double check that the stack were newly installed and it shows right now timestamp. It fails on stack setup within a new dummy project and has the same signature of long ugly errors including linker error on Main.o bad relocation .  Here is the core of it (same as at top):

```
Cannot open /Users/steve/.stack/setup-exe-src/setup-mPHDZzAJ.o: bad relocation (Invalid pointer diff) in section __TEXT/__text (r1_address=21c, r1_type=5, r1_extern=1, r1_length=2, r1_pcrel=0, r1_symbolnum=37), (r2_address=21c, r2_type=0, r2_extern=1, r2_length=2, r2_pcrel=0, r2_symbolnum=30)
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
`gcc' failed in phase `Linker'. (Exit code: 1)

--  While building simple Setup.hs using:
      /Users/steve/.stack/programs/x86_64-osx/ghc-8.8.3/bin/ghc-8.8.3 
     -rtsopts -threaded -clear-package-db -global-package-db -hide-all-packages -package base -main-is StackSetupShim.mainOverride -package Cabal-3.0.1.0 /Users/steve/.stack/setup-exe-src/setup-mPHDZzAJ.hs /Users/steve/.stack/setup-exe-src/setup-shim-mPHDZzAJ.hs -o /Users/steve/.stack/setup-exe-cache/x86_64-osx/tmp-Cabal-simple_mPHDZzAJ_3.0.1.0_ghc-8.8.3
    Process exited with code: ExitFailure 1
```

Comment: That kinda looks like a corrupted installation to me. How did you install stack? Did you install GHC and/or Cabal separately?

Comment: `brew install stack`

Comment: I just tried to do this myself by following the cursory instructions (more link hints actually..) on `haskell platform` page: details above.  Summary :  `ghcup` good , `cabal-install` bad.

Comment: @javadba You shouldn’t need to install `ghcup` or `cabal-install` — `stack` should subsume the functionality of both of those.

Comment: @javadba You should be following the official installation instructions: https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/README/#how-to-install

Comment: @bradrn  I just tried from the `haskellstack` link and the  same errors as beginning of my question. I did double check that the `stack` were newly installed and it shows right now timestamp. It fails on `stack setup` within a new dummy project and has the same signature of long ugly errors including  linker error on `Main.o bad relocation`

Comment: @bradrn Are you sure? I thought stack didn't expose its cabal, etc. outside of itself, so you did have to install with ghcup separately if you wanted to use it outside of stack.

Comment: the `ghcup` was only separate from / before I tried the `haskellstack`.   i'll check if my question were not making that clear.  OK i updated the very end of the question to make this more clear. See *Another Update*

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica I am sure. You can use `cabal` through Stack by doing `stack exec -- cabal <your-arguments>`; this is what I do on the rare occasions when I need it.

Comment: @bradrn I guess it's a matter of semantics. I don't consider it "outside of stack" if I have to prefix calls to it with `stack exec --`.

Comment: resolved: there was a known bug. details in my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found this known bug:  https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/issues/4373

That is exactly what I'm seeing.

[image]

The workaround required is to update a `settings` file that is buried deep under a newly generated `~/.stack` directory  https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/issues/4373#issuecomment-432726112

[image]

Those instructions are incomplete so I added a comment to that bug to clarify.   That settings location:  `~/.stack/programs/x86_64-osx/ghc-8.8.3/lib/ghc-8.8.3/settings`

[image]

And this *works*  (note that `stack test` is a combination of `stack build` and `stack test`):

```
(base) 10:27:09/haskelltest $stack test
Stack has not been tested with GHC versions above 8.6, and using 8.8.3, this may fail
Stack has not been tested with Cabal versions above 2.4, but version 3.0.1.0 was found, this may fail
Linking /Users/steve/.stack/setup-exe-cache/x86_64-osx/tmp-Cabal-simple_mPHDZzAJ_3.0.1.0_ghc-8.8.3 ...
clang-9: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-no-pie' [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
clang-9: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-no-pie' [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
Building all executables for `haskelltest' once. After a successful build of all of them, only specified executables will be rebuilt.
haskelltest> configure (lib + exe + test)
Configuring haskelltest-0.1.0.0...
clang-9: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-no-pie' [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
haskelltest> build (lib + exe + test)
Preprocessing library for haskelltest-0.1.0.0..
Building library for haskelltest-0.1.0.0..
[1 of 2] Compiling Lib
[2 of 2] Compiling Paths_haskelltest
Preprocessing test suite 'haskelltest-test' for haskelltest-0.1.0.0..
Building test suite 'haskelltest-test' for haskelltest-0.1.0.0..
[1 of 2] Compiling Main
[2 of 2] Compiling Paths_haskelltest
Linking .stack-work/dist/x86_64-osx/Cabal-3.0.1.0/build/haskelltest-test/haskelltest-test ...
clang-9: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-no-pie' [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
clang-9: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-no-pie' [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
Preprocessing executable 'haskelltest-exe' for haskelltest-0.1.0.0..
Building executable 'haskelltest-exe' for haskelltest-0.1.0.0..
[1 of 2] Compiling Main
[2 of 2] Compiling Paths_haskelltest
Linking .stack-work/dist/x86_64-osx/Cabal-3.0.1.0/build/haskelltest-exe/haskelltest-exe ...
clang-9: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-no-pie' [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
clang-9: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-no-pie' [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
haskelltest> copy/register
Installing library in /git/rubytest/haskelltest/.stack-work/install/x86_64-osx/18cf924ea0be80a27100889c349bd98b50cf064de8de23f912f9f822b43a80db/8.8.3/lib/x86_64-osx-ghc-8.8.3/haskelltest-0.1.0.0-48zsyNIR9r7Efmr0ATZ6Im
Installing executable haskelltest-exe in /git/rubytest/haskelltest/.stack-work/install/x86_64-osx/18cf924ea0be80a27100889c349bd98b50cf064de8de23f912f9f822b43a80db/8.8.3/bin
Registering library for haskelltest-0.1.0.0..
haskelltest> test (suite: haskelltest-test)

Progress 1/2: haskelltestTest suite not yet implemented

haskelltest> Test suite haskelltest-test passed
Completed 2 action(s).
```