# Tradeoffs for gcc configuration options when installing via brew

Tags: macos, gcc

A coworker and I have both have macbook pro's with macOS 14.x installed.  We are starting a project that is using `haskell`.  We ended up with sharply divergent results in installing the `haskell stack`.  His installation breezed through: my experience was quite different.

After some tribulations it was discovered the root of my issues were essentially that `gcc` linker were not happy: so it was changed  to `clang`   https://stackoverflow.com/a/61032017/1056563.  But then - why did the original settings using `gcc` work for him?

The primary suspect in my mind is a different set of options or installation mechanism for the `gcc`.  Here is how I installed it:

```
brew install gcc --enable-cxx --enable-fortran --use-llvm
```

I am uncertain of how *he* installed but am guessing he used the default

```
brew install gcc
```

What then are the differences in behavior - and what gotchas would I run into if I were to uninstall `brew` and use the defaults.  One thing is that one or more of my *other* packages would become unhappy since the `install` options used were copied from the package instructions. I just do not happen to remember exactly which one had that stipulation.  Some of the packages I have built from source off the top of my head:

- scientific python   numpy/scikit-learn etc.
- deep learning   tf, pytorch
- opencv
- R and a bunch of R libraries

Is there any general guidance on most robust settings?  `Robust` here meaning: will cover the widest swath of build-from-source requirements.

**Update** My co-worker has determined the following

> I just confirmed that on my macbook I have system gcc (not from homebrew), which is a wrapper around clang
>   looks like installing gcc from homebrew might be contra-indicated in this case

So my question still stands - but this information sheds light on the discrepancies of behavior for `haskell stack`